# cocos2d ccTintTo, implementing an endless changing color label

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

Instead of writing all those lines at the init method of HelloWorldLayer :

```
 CCTintTo* tint1 = [CCTintTo actionWithDuration:2 red:255 green:0 blue:0];
 CCTintTo* tint2 = [CCTintTo actionWithDuration:2 red:0 green:0 blue:255];
 ....
 CCSequence* sequence = [CCSequence actions:tint1, tint2, nil];
 [label runAction:sequence];
```

I tried to make the label change color forever but got stucked:
I don't know where to place the relavant commands+ dealing with the integers x,y,z
I tried to do the randomize process at the update method,but didn't have any access to the label, any ideas?

```
//  HelloWorldLayer.h
//  Essentials
//
//  Created by Steffen Itterheim on 14.07.10.
//  Copyright Steffen Itterheim 2010. All rights reserved.
//

#import "cocos2d.h"

@interface HelloWorld : CCLayer

{
    CCTintTo* tint1;
    CCSequence* sequence1;
   // CCLabelTTF* label; even tried property
}

// returns a Scene that contains the HelloWorld as the only child
+(id) scene;

@end
```

---

```
//
//  HelloWorldLayer.m
//  Essentials
//
//  Created by Steffen Itterheim on 14.07.10.
//  Copyright Steffen Itterheim 2010. All rights reserved.
//

#import "HelloWorldScene.h"

#import "MenuScene.h"
 integer_t x;
 integer_t y;
 integer_t z;

@implementation HelloWorld


+(id) scene
{
    CCScene* scene = [CCScene node];
    CCLayer* layer = [HelloWorld node];
    [scene addChild:layer];
    return scene;
}

-(id) init
{
    if ((self = [super init]))
    {

        CCLOG(@"init %@", self);

        // enable touch input
        self.isTouchEnabled = YES;

        CGSize size = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];


        // add the "touch to continue" label
        CCLabelTTF* label = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"Touch Screen For Awesome" fontName:@"AmericanTypewriter-Bold" fontSize:30];
        label.position = CGPointMake(size.width / 2, size.height / 8);
        [self addChild:label];

        [self schedule:@selector(update:) interval:1/60.0f];
/*
        tint1 = [CCTintTo actionWithDuration:2 red:x green:y blue:z];
        sequence1 = [CCSequence actions:tint1, nil ];
        id goaction=[CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:sequence1];
        [label runAction:goaction];

    */
   }
    return self;
}

-(void) registerWithTouchDispatcher
{
    // call the base implementation (default touch handler)
    [super registerWithTouchDispatcher];
    //[[CCTouchDispatcher sharedDispatcher] addTargetedDelegate:self priority:INT_MIN+1 swallowsTouches:YES];
}

-(void) update:(ccTime)delta
{

    x=(integer_t )(CCRANDOM_0_1()*255); y=(integer_t )(CCRANDOM_0_1()*255); z=(integer_t )(CCRANDOM_0_1()*255);
    tint1 = [CCTintTo actionWithDuration:2 red:x green:y blue:z ];
    sequence1 = [CCSequence actions:tint1, nil ];
    [HelloWorld.label runAction:goaction]; //property label not found on object of type 'HelloWorld'

}

// Touch Input Events
-(CGPoint) locationFromTouches:(NSSet *)touches
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView: [touch view]];
    return [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:touchLocation];
}

-(void) ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
}

-(void) ccTouchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    CGPoint location = [self locationFromTouches:touches];
    CCLOG(@"touch moved to: %.0f, %.0f", location.x, location.y);
}

-(void) ccTouchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    // the scene we want to see next
    CCScene* scene = [MenuScene scene];
    CCTransitionSlideInR* transitionScene = [CCTransitionSlideInR transitionWithDuration:3 scene:scene];
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:transitionScene];

}

-(void) ccTouchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

}


-(void) dealloc
{
    CCLOG(@"dealloc: %@", self);

    // always call [super dealloc] at the end of every dealloc method
    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want the tint color to be random for each time, then you cannot use `CCTintTo` directly inside `CCRepeatForever`. You need to re-randomize the RGB values for each `CCTintTo` action. Thus you need to embed the randomization process inside the action by using block. Here is how:

```
// do this in init method

__block void (^changeTint)(CCNode*) = [[^(CCNode *node) {
    GLubyte x = (integer_t)(CCRANDOM_0_1()*255), y = (integer_t)(CCRANDOM_0_1()*255), z = (integer_t)(CCRANDOM_0_1()*255);
    [node runAction:[CCSequence actionOne:[CCTintTo actionWithDuration:2 red:x green:y blue:z]
                                      two:[CCCallBlockN actionWithBlock:changeTint]]];
} copy] autorelease];

changeTint(label);
```

Comment: I had the impression that he just needed to repeat the tinting.. Either ways, your answer does indeed randomize the tint, but I fail to see how the process repeats? Should he dispatch a GCD task that repeats every [tint interval duration]?

Comment: @Mazyod The process repeats by recursion. The `changeTint` block recurse itself by sending `CCCallBlockN` that use the block as the parameter. Therefore, that single `changeTint(label)` call starts an infinitely repeated process.

Comment: (+1) Damn, I am sooo out-dated. You taught me something awesome. Thanks. (That's not real recursion, right? There is no recursion stack in this case, I think. The function stack is just one call, AFAIK).

Comment: @Mazyod Yup, it's not a real recursion with stacks and all that. Basically the block schedules itself to be called again and again; I guess it's a pseudo-recursion :)

Answer (score 1):

You should look at `CCRepeatForever` action. As the name implies, it will repeat the action it points to forever. So you should remove your update method where you are changing the colors, and return to the `CCSequence` code that you had, and embed that in a `CCRepeatForever` action:

```
CCTintTo* tint1 = [CCTintTo actionWithDuration:2 red:255 green:0 blue:0];
CCTintTo* tint2 = [CCTintTo actionWithDuration:2 red:0 green:0 blue:255];
....
CCSequence* sequence = [CCSequence actions:tint1, tint2, nil];
CCAction* repeat  = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:sequence];
[label runAction:repeat];
```